# Extract an execution thread into minimal java

Tags: java, dependency-management

Is there a tool that can trace code execution and generate cut-down Java classes that capture the methods that actually got executed?  I'm trying to pull some code out of
a big codebase without including tons of static dependencies.  Dynamic dependency
extraction.

For example if method M of class C is never executed, the extracted code would leave that method out, along with everything that method uses and depends upon.

Comment: "Is there a tool that can trace code execution and generate cut-down Java classes that capture the methods that actually got executed?" - Yes, it is called a Java Profiler. The rest of what you are asking, I don't know if it is at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

While it would be possible to create such a thing, it would depend on the runs being deterministic. If something changes, you'd get a `MethodNotFoundError` when the control flow changes due to differences to the original run.

Imagine doing that to some calendar code, and then suddenly it's a leap year and the code that was "optimized away" needs to be run? Not a very robust solution, so not a part of a standard developer toolkit.

If you're trying to extract relevant code out of a spaghetti codebase, you could try running a profiler (`jvisualvm`) to see what code is being run. This would require that you get the software to the state that it's only running the code you're interested in, but so would your initial idea.

Comment: Absent reflection and dynamic loading, any missing method references will give you compilation errors, so it wouldn't be hard to make the process deterministic.

Comment: @AlanWendt you wanted to get rid of methods that are never executed. Those are not the same as "methods that are never referred to in code". If code refers to 4 methods in different branches, and only one is ever executed, how many methods do you want to keep? If all of them, then there's nothing special about that and this "dynamic dependency extraction" is hogwash. I was talking about a solution where you modify the bytecode **after compilation** and after a profiling run to see which execution paths are taken.